# How do you get RequestMapping request in AOP advice from a Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, http, logging, aop

Given some kind of controller with a request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value="/some/path", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

How would you retrieve the method value (RequestMethod.POST) in the aspect class?

I want to keep track of all the controller methods that perform a POST request.

Thanks

Comment: Get the `@Controller` bean, get the invoked method, retrieve the annotation, get its `method` attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
public void controller() {}

// In advice
MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
Method method = methodSignature .getMethod();
RequestMethod[] requestMethods = method.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).method();
```

Be careful of which class you import.

Comment: I still think that this is not the way it should be done. My own answer uses canonical AspectJ and does not require reflection.

Answer (score 10):

@AL13N: Your own answer is correct, but you do not need to use reflection if you just bind the annotation to a parameter. Here is an example in POJO + AspectJ. In Spring AOP it should be the same, though:

**Sample controller with main method:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/some/path", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyController controller = new MyController();
        controller.foo();
        controller.bar();
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

public aspect RequestMappingInterceptor {
    @Pointcut(
        "within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *) && " +
        "@annotation(requestMapping) && " +
        "execution(* *(..))"
    )
    public void controller(RequestMapping requestMapping) {}

    @Before("controller(requestMapping)")
    public void advice(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, RequestMapping requestMapping) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        System.out.println("  " + requestMapping);
        System.out.println("  " + requestMapping.method()[0]);
    }
}
```

BTW, the `&& execution(* *(..))` part of the pointcut is probably not necessary in Spring AOP because it just knows execution pointcuts anyway. In AspectJ you need to exclude `call()` and other types of pointcuts because AspectJ is more powerful. It does not hurt though and is safer and more explicit.

**Console output:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyController.foo())
  @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping(headers=[], name=, value=[/some/path], produces=[], method=[POST], params=[], consumes=[])
  POST
foo
bar
```

**Edit:** Swapped parameters so as to make the joinpoint the first advice method parameter, because Spring AOP seems to insist on this order while AspectJ does not.

Comment: I tried your solution and it doesn't seem to be working. Getting error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut.

Comment: It works for me. Did you make a mistake in your copy & paste action?

Comment: Somebody mentioned a while ago that for Spring AOP he had to put the `JoinPoint` parameter at the beginning of the advice signature instead of at the end. I doubt that this is true, but you can try. I am by no means a Spring expert.

Comment: As for the possible copy & paste error: Have you noticed that my pointcut has a parameter in its signature? ;-)

Comment: I too am getting error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut with this solution. No copy and paste mistake...

Comment: The solution definitely works (the console output proves it), I can say nothing else unless you show me your code and configuration.

Comment: Why the downvote? Downvotes are reserved for answers showing a significant lack of research effort or being sloppily written. My code is fully self-consistent, compileable and runs. Just try! I even posted the console log. If it does not run in your environment you must have changed something in an incorrect way.

Comment: @kriegaex I had the same error than Andy (error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut)  until I set the JointPoint as first param in signature